# Problemas com FindSystemTimeZoneById em Web.API .NET Core em Docker (Linux)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, docker, asp.net-core

**Cenário:**

Estou migrando uma WebAPI para .NET Core, no Windows está rodando normalmente.

**Problema**

Quando estou executando no Docker (Linux) (docker-compose) estou tendo o seguinte problema:

> "The time zone ID 'W. Europe Standard Time' was not
>   found on the local computer."

**Código onde ocorre:**

```
public static DateTime ConvertDateToLanguage(DateTime dDateLocal)
{
    var sqlServerRepository = new SqlServerRepository();
    var cstZone =
        TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(
            sqlServerRepository.GetImpostazioniSkin().FirstOrDefault()?.FusoOrario ?? string.Empty);
    var cstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dDateLocal.ToUniversalTime(), cstZone);
    return cstTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voltando no tempo um pouco lembrei que o Linux tem a nomenclatura de TimeZone diferente do Windows

No Windows temos por exemplo **Eastern Standard Time**

No Linux temos **America/New_York**

Achei interessante que tem uma ferramenta que faz a conversão:

É possivel realizar a conversão utilizando **TimeZoneConverter**

**Exemplo:**

```
string tz = TZConvert.IanaToWindows("America/New_York");
// Result:  "Eastern Standard Time"

string tz = TZConvert.WindowsToIana("Eastern Standard Time");
// result:  "America/New_York"

string tz = TZConvert.WindowsToIana("Eastern Standard Time", "CA");
// result:  "America/Toronto"
```

Portanto, utilizando **America/New York** por exemplo funcionou.

**Extraí as informações daqui:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348807/how-to-translate-between-windows-and-iana-time-zones